# Как менять код ошибки на OK(200) в ASP.NET во время валидации

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, атрибуты

Задача следующая.

Хочу валидировать у модели конкретное поле.
Задать атрибут данному полю нельзя т.к. модель не моя.

Валидация работает впринципе,но возвращает 400 код. Однако, необходимо возвращать в виде кода ответа 200.

Делаю значит следующим образом:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromCustomBody] MyModel model)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Где FromCustomBody это ValidationAttribute, со всеми параметрами от FromBody.

В ответ приходит код 400.

Судя по learn.microsoft.com, в этом виноват ApiController (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#automatic-http-400-responses)

Так что варианта решения два:

1. С помощью атрибутов авторизации производить Serilaze модели и проверять конкретные поля на валидацию. А после кидать возврат контекста (аля фильтры)
2. Подменять коды 400 на 200 на уровне мидлварок или подобных штук.

В общем, прошу помощи как сделать это лучше.

Просто написать валидацию в методе нельзя т.к. именно этого и хочу избежать данным действием.

Comment: Так все верно, если данные не проходят валидацию, то это 400. Никаких 200 там быть не может. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290198/12888024

Comment: @aepot я хочу подменять код 400 на 200.

Я щас пытаюсь с помощью ActionFilterAttribute попробовать прочитать тело запроса и если что возвращать OkResult().

В общем беда...

Моя главная задача - если конкретное поле некорректно, возвращать 200, без входа в метод роута.

Comment: 200 должен содержать ответ, что мешает это в методе реализовать?

Comment: В общем реализовал с помощью Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter

В OnResourceExecutionAsync(...) просто сделал серелизацию Body и проверк.

возврат .Result = new OkRestul();
И всё ок становится.